# Famous pieces in the Louvre

Tags: paris, museums, the-louvre

Besides the Mona Lisa and the Venus de Milo, what are the don't-miss pieces of the Louvre's permanent collection?

Comment: What kind of art are you interested in? What kind of art can you easily see at home? That'll make a big difference on what things you should try to see, and what bits you can safely leave for a future visit so you can concentrate on the bits that are special for you!

Comment: I think this question is too broad in current form.

Comment: I find this question and answers to be constructive: most people will spend a small fortune to visit the Louvre and must prioritize what they see: this provides prioritization guidance.   I feel that if the community has a problem with the question then it should help the OP to pose a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find almost everything about Louvre's permanent exhibits and events in the [museum's site](http://www.louvre.fr/en/homepage). Famous permanent exhibits that I'd personally wouldn't miss are:

- The [Winged Victory of Samothrace](http://www.louvre.fr/en/oeuvre-notices/winged-victory-samothrace?selection=44909),
- Nicolas Poussin's painting [The Rape of the Sabine Women](http://www.louvre.fr/en/oeuvre-notices/rape-sabine-women?selection=44909), and
- Eugène Delacroix's painting [July 28: Liberty Leading the People](http://www.louvre.fr/en/oeuvre-notices/july-28-liberty-leading-people?selection=44909).

You can find more about the Louvre's permanent exhibits on the site's [Selected Works section](http://www.louvre.fr/en/selections/masterpieces?page=2).

Answer (score 3):

In mesopotamian collections, don't miss the [code of Hammurabi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_Hammurabi) found in Susa (Shush, Iran), the first written law in the world.